# If I want to develop Layered Service Provider to support all Windows OS's, what problems should I expect?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock-lsp

I want to develop simple HTTP filter (transparent proxy).

I want it to support all versions of Windows including XP and above.

From the folks that have experience with this, what problems should iIexpect when installing the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some that I could quickly think of on top of my head:

-You should be aware that you have to cover all browsers or at least major ones like IE, firefox, chrome, safari and opera. The ways they use Winsock are different, eg overlapped vs. non-overlapped IO.

-Installation/Uninstallation is challenging as it's very easy to mess up and end up losing internet connection.

-It is even more challenging if there is other LSPs already installed. Your LSP might interfere other LSPs and vice versa.

-It's very common that Windows PCs pre-installed with anti-virus. Some of them provides proxy-like internet filter as well, eg. Avast and Kaspersky. As being winsock applications, anti-viruses are also loaded with and controlled by your LSP. Once your LSP breaks these antivirus and their net filters, expect no network connection for any other apps on your computer.

I could list more but that could cast away your hunger to dive into this challenge. Start doing it first and you will get know it better along the way. Good luck!